# Is it possible to make a second Many-to-many relationship between 2 tables in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations

my goal here is to add a second join table between two tables :
I got one table User
I got one table Tirage
And I already created a join table Participate,
here is the "associations" and Participate model code :

Participate :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Participe = sequelize.define("participe", {
        uuid: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
        },
        cadeauA: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID
        },
        participantId: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID
        },
        tirageId: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID
        },
        isAdmin: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
        },
        selfGranted: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    });
    return Participe;
  };
```

Association :

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.participe, foreignKey:'cadeauA', foreignKey:'participantId'});
db.tirages.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: db.participe, foreignKey:'tirageId'});
```

*(Note that I didn't check yet if the second foreign key in the first line works, so if it's not it's kinda normal).*

It works, I can manage to get all tirages from users who are "participating" thanks to :

```
exports.getUserInvitation = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      uuid: req.params.participant
    },
    include: Tirage,
    as: 'tirages'
  });
  return res.status(200).send(user.tirages);
}
```

**So now**, I would like to add an other junction table, not to see if a user is participating to a tirage but if he is invited to the tirage.
I tried mutliple things but it just won't work or even break the "participate" feature.
I read the entire association doc from sequelize but nothing is really helpfull for multiple many-to-many association between two tables.

What I tried :

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.invitation, foreignKey:'invite', foreignKey:'admin'});
db.tirages.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: db.invitation, foreignKey:'tirageId'});
```

```
db.invitations.belongsTo(db.users, {foreignKey:'admin', foreignKey:'invite'});
db.invitations.belongsTo(db.tirages, {foreignKey:'_tirage'});
```

And many other things that I don't remember.

Edit :

I would like to say that I tested it :

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'invite', foreignKey:'admin'});
db.tirages.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'tirageId'});
```

but when I do

```
await user.addTirage(tirage, { through: Invitation });
```

It adds a Participate record (even if I specify the through table).

Answer (score 0):

**First**, if you indicate the same key `foreignKey` twice JS will keep only the last one.
**Second**, Sequelize **does not** support composite foreign keys.
**Third**, to distinguish associations from the same tables to the other same tables you need to indicate aliases in associations and also in each query where you need to include associated models.
Let's assume you use one column from each table to join with junction tables then it might look like this:

```js
db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.participe, foreignKey:'participantId', as: 'participatingTirages'});
db.tirages.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: db.participe, foreignKey:'tirageId', as: 'participatedUsers'}); 

db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'invite', as: 'invitatingTirages'});
db.tirages.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'tirageId', as: 'invitedUsers'});
```

Now, you can add a tirage with invitation like this (maybe I make mistake in the name of the method, try to find out the real one):

```js
await user.addInvitingTirage(tirage);
```

OR to add a tirage to participate in:

```js
await user.addParticipatingTirage(tirage);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! But now, I tried to add my other foreign keys like : ``` db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'invite', as: 'invitatingTirages'});
db.users.belongsToMany(db.tirages, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'admin', as: 'adminTirage'});
db.tirages.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: db.invitations, foreignKey:'tirageId', as: 'invitedUsers'}); ```` Is it the good way to do it ? Because now I don't know how to add the field "admin" (for exemple) in the invitation table

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the same table for multiple many-to-many relations.